# Django calculation based on calculated value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I need your help once more. I am working on a project for my wargaming group. It is a simple ranking site. So we have players, they participate in tournaments and get points. I got to the point where I am able to assign players to tournaments, assign place they took at the tournament to their name.

Now I have to calculate points. Algorithm is simple, but I have problems passing a value from `Tournament` model to `Ranking`. Each Tournament has a calculated rating (based on other things, mostly bigger tournament, bigger rating) and in other models, I was unable to use it and need your help with it. On top of that, it would be awesome if changing a rating value in Tournament would force an update of all dependent calculations.

So we have models like that:

```
 class Player(models.Model):
    class Meta:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nicname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    army = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tournament(models.Model):
    class Meta:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date')
    player_num = models.IntegerField
    points = models.FloatField(default=1000.00)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And then I have a ranking model of this kind:

```
class TournamentStandings(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_place = models.FloatField
```

In admin.py I do calculations for TournamentAdmin:

```
fields = ['name', 'date', 'player_num', 'points', 'get_rating']
def get_rating(self, obj):
    return obj.points / 100.00
```

And now I would like to make calculation for TournamentStandingsAdmin:

```
def player_points(self, obj):
    return (obj.tournament.player_num/obj.player_place)* obj.tournament.get_rating
```

But the result is an error

> 'Tournament' object has no attribute 'get_rating'

So my guess is my calculated *get_rating* is not a true model field but how to work around that?

Comment: If you want to call the method on the model, then you need to actually define it on the model, not on the admin class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Daniel suggested you need to add `get_rating` method to your `Tournament` model.

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date')
    player_num = models.IntegerField
    points = models.FloatField(default=1000.00)

    ....
    def get_rating(self):
        return obj.points / 100.00
```

After that you can call the method with a `Tournament` object as follows:

```
obj.tournament.get_rating
```